# Ursina problem with the priority of Entity

Tags: python, entity, ursina

i have a problem with entity priorities.
I created two 2D 'quad' entities with different colors, but when they appear on the screen sometimes the color of one prevails and other times that of the other.

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

o = Entity(model='quad', scale_x=0.3, scale_y=0.3, collider="box", color=color.red,position=(-0.45,-1.4))
Re_bianco = Entity(model='quad', scale_x=0.3, scale_y=0.3, collider="box", position=(-0.5,-1.4))
app.run()
```

[image: white quad]
[image: red quad]

I tried to use the z axis, but the result is not optimal because by offsetting the z axis the quarter distorts.
and even overlapping them you can see both.

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

o = Entity(model='quad', scale_x=0.3, scale_y=0.3, collider="box", color=color.red,position=(-0.5,-1.4,0))
Re_bianco = Entity(model='quad', scale_x=0.3, scale_y=0.3, collider="box", position=(-0.5,-1.4,1))
app.run()
```

[image: red_white_quad]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Currently both entities are at the same depth, 0. How can the program know  which one should be rendered above the other?
You can specify this by giving a third position value, for example, position=(-0.45, -1.4, **-1**), which would be in front of an entity at position (-0.5, -1.4, **0**)